# Subtotal with count if date range

Tags: excel

I am trying to add the subtotal function to be able to count only the filtered values. I want to count only the employees that have been hired in 2022. So, my table looks something like this:

| Name | Group | Hiring Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | A | 13/01/2022 |
| Peter | B | 12/01/2022 |
| Wesley | B | 07/03/2022 |
| Jennifer | B | 18/12/2021 |

I was using this formula and it was working ok (where the output is equals to 3).

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C5,">01/01/2022")
```

However now my desired output in case I filter "Group B" for example will be 2.

I know that I should use subtotal but I couldn´t add the formula correctly. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: [This may be useful](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Excel, COUNTIFS may work.

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C5, ">31/12/2021", B2:B5, "B")
```